# find files older than X days in bash and delete

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory with a few TB of files. I'd like to delete every file in it that is older than 14 days.

I thought I would use `find . -mtime +13 -delete`. To make sure the command works as expected I ran `find . -mtime +13 -exec /bin/ls -lh '{}' \; | grep '<today>'`. The latter should return nothing, since files that were created/modified today should not be found by `find` using `-mtime +13`. To my surprise, however, `find` just spew out a list of all the files modified/created today!

Comment: Are you sure you or someone else have not modified the files?!

Comment: See `-daystart` option for find. Your find counts exactly 24*13 hours backwards, leaving files which might be 24*13 - 1 minute and later your another find will find those.

Comment: Just figured it out! The reason is `ls`. `find` finds a directory with mtime +13 and `ls` simply list all it's content no matter what mtime the files have (facepalm!).

Comment: You could use option `-d` for the `ls` to show just the directory name instead of all its contents.

Comment: Always test your find command first by replacing "-delete" with "-print". It may also include the current directory (.) in the result list, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: at first you find files 13 days old, list this details by /bin/ls, and at the end you filter out this by grep, because you filter only today files. this is allways empty set. logical bug :)

Answer (score 64):

```
find your/folder -type f -mtime +13 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for filenames containing spaces. Either (GNU specific) `find -delete` or `find -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

Comment: @grebneke: can you back up your statement with examples or facts? `find`'s `{}` is well-known to be safe regarding spaces and funny symbols in file names.

Comment: This does work for filenames with spaces for me redhat linux/bash.

Comment: Just enclose the {} in quotes: `find your/folder -type f -mtime +13 -exec rm "{}" \;`

Comment: No need for extra `xargs` command, just use ```find your/folder -type f -mtime +13 -delete```

Comment: `find /path/to/dir -type f -mtime +13 -exec rm {} +` is more efficient if there are large number of resulting files. `{} +` constructs the command line by appending each selected file name at the end and run the command only once.

Comment: find with -exec rm {} badly interpret spaces, but you can use option -delete  that respects all exotic file names. additional pipe and process with xargs is non sense.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me.

```
$ find ./folder_name/*  -type f -mtime +13 -print | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: The `-r` switch is useless. Moreover, you'll run into problems if you have filenames containing spaces or other funny symbols. Use `-print0` and `xargs -0 ...` if your utilities support them, otherwise, use @Mindx's answer. Or, if your `find` supports it, use the `-delete` test of `find` as so: `find ./folder_name  -type f -mtime +13 -delete`.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: using asterisk  find ./folder_name/* is mistake, because shell will expand '*' info all items existent in this folder. When folder keeps extremally huge items (files or directories), it will exceed maximum arguments or max characters for execute command. Better remove '*' signt, this will do the same, without any automated shel expand. but if you need to find specified names, use option -name 'some*thing' and give expansion directly to find internals.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution to this is in @navid's and @gniourf_gniourf's comments. Because it's buried in the comments, I'd like to bring it up to be more visible.

`find your/folder -type f -mtime +13 -delete`

This avoids any possible issues with spaces and whatnot in the filenames and it doesn't spin up another executable to do the deleting so it should be faster too.

I tried and tested this.

Comment: this is the best solution. for what using xargs and external rm command, when 'find' support -delete option? with this there are no unneeded pipe, forks, multpile execute external command. this will speed up execution, and prevents problems with exotic characters in file names, and white characters.

Comment: Doesn't `-delete` have a limit of how many files it can delete? This limit should be identified and documented in this answer.

Comment: I looked through the man page of `find` but there was no mention of any kind of limit on the number of files to be deleted.