# How to get difference a date greater than 6 calendar days in shell script

Tags: shell

I am working on a script to delete data older than 5 days, I created a shell like below to get the date that is older than 5 days. But now it is month starting and now it is giving -ve results. Any suggestions to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

```
    fi
DD=$(date +%d)
MM=$(date +%m )
YYYY=$(date +%Y)
DM=`expr $DD - 6 `

if [ "$DM" -lt 10 ]; then
```

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: why don't you use `find` for this? `-mtime` and so work very well.

Comment: I suspect that the answer to your _real_ question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20238183/2088135

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the correct tool for the job is probably `find` but one alternative would be to work in seconds:

```
now=$(date +%s)
six_days_in_seconds=$(( 60 * 60 * 24 * 6 ))

six_days_ago=$(( now - six_days_in_seconds ))
```

If you have GNU date, then you can just pass a string instead of doing the calculation yourself:

```
date --date '6 days ago' +%s
```

As you can see, these two options give the same result:

```
printf 'First: %s\nSecond: %s\n' "$(( $(date +%s) - 60 * 60 * 24 * 6 ))" \
                                 "$(date --date '6 days ago' +%s)"
First: 1480159605
Second: 1480159605
```

Comment: You can also say `date --date "6 days ago" "+%s"`.

Comment: @fedorqui if you've got GNU date you can, yes. Edited to include that option.

Comment: I tried last option but it is giving out put in Unix time..i wanted to have in general date for the calendar month.

Comment: If you have GNU date and are using `-d '6 days ago'`, you can specify the format however you want. `%s` can be changed to whatever format string you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but using `find` will delete all files in a directory older than 5 days

```
 find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used following syntax and it worked well.

`day = $(date +%Y.%m.%d -d "6 days ago")`